# embedding Latest webchat on sharepoint modern site

Tags: sharepoint, direct-line-botframework

i have one sharepoint modern site and i am using it as masterpage. i want to embed the microsoft webchat on this master page using the Js provided by microsoft.
help me to make it possible.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, customizing master page is not supported on modern sites currently. You could refer to this article for more:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/modern-experience-customizations-customize-sites

You could try to use embed web part on a modern page to embed the webchat. Read this article about using the embed web part:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/add-content-to-your-page-using-the-embed-web-part-721f3b2f-437f-45ef-ac4e-df29dba74de8